# Unable to use jquery within chrome local storage, how to use .remove() jquery method for css :has pseudoselector using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So I have used the line of jquery successfully elsewhere, but now I need to run it inside a chrome extension.

Also, alert works perfectly, so the problem is the line of jquery not working here.

When I look in the inspection, I see the error "$ is undefined". Perhaps there is another way to do this exact thing below with pure javascript?

```
(function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('mystoreitem-aaa', function(results) {
        if (results['mystoreitem-aaa']) {
            // alert("hi");
            $('.someclasslala:has(div.anotherclasslala)').remove();
        };
        return;
    });
})();
```

---

update - was able to resolve the undefined jquery error on the page by including the jquery script before the script above in the manifest:

```
  "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "js/jquery.js""js/myscript.js" ],
```

However, the code is not working on the page, which is weird, because the alert above it is working which means the code is injected properly... I think I'm going to change this to not just run the jquery but inject a new script into the head with the jquery instead.

---

SOLVED!! (solution to the issue moved to an answer format below as requested)

Comment: Have you tried this: `(function($) {...code here....})(jQuery);`

Comment: include `(jQuery)` at the end?

Comment: If I do that, I receive the following error: `Error in response to storage.get: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: try including `$` instead of `jquery` at the end..

Comment: That results in the same as the former error, `Error in response to storage.get: ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: problems solved, updated description.

Comment: @johnsmith, err, the question is a question, not a hybrid of a question and answer. It'd be much more helpful for anyone encountering the same issue if you add it as a separate answer and accept it as a solution and rollback the edit of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!!

so the first thing was including jquery in the manifest above, which is not necessary if I include a script into the head. But the reason it wasn't working AFTER it was no longer giving the error is because I needed to change the script to run at document_end NOT document_start. Because the element that was to be removed needed to be loaded first.

This issue is solved!

note - it is worth noting, that, probably due to asynchronous loading issue, this javascript won't work if I just inject it into the head. it works however if I do the manifest as above and set it to load at document_end.